# FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED not working on newer android

Tags: android, security

I have been implementing [tapjacking defence](https://medium.com/devknoxio/what-is-tapjacking-in-android-and-how-to-prevent-it-50140e57bf44) in android app, but I found out that flag `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED` is set on android 7.0, but not on android 10.0 while window is obscured by another application.

Do you have any idea why is happens?

I tested it on both emulators and physical devices. Testing application for overlay was [twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux&hl=cs). [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent) feels useless.

I found this comment:

> The FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED only works if the overlay relays touch
> events, AND if the touched coordinates is actually obscured

which could suggest, that in newer android versions it must also obscure touch coordinates, but I could not find any app that obscures touched coordinates to test it.

In order to have centralized detection of overlayed apps I used:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final boolean obscuredTouch = (event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) != 0;
        if(obscuredTouch) return false;

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

in BaseActivity which all other activities extends.

Android tag
`android:filterTouchesWhenObscured`
for views uses the same flag `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED` underneath I suppose (correct me if I am wrong):

Comment: Android 8 brought overlay window changes and I'm pretty sure you can no longer intercept any touch. From my experience all touch events that system dispatches to your floating window are considered consumed regardless of what you return from `dispatchTouchEvent`.

Comment: If I return false in `dispatchTouchEvent` regardless android system version, it intercepts touch. Problem I got here is with flag `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED` that is not recognized.

Comment: @Hourglasser have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @Jules I've gone through the issue with 3rd party security team that is specialized in mobile apps security and it is not possible - we gotta use their 3rd party app shield solution anyway, that might avoid the issue. Android system does not support it in higher versions (did not find any documentation about it but it just stops working). 

So I just left there code for lower android versions.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED no longer triggers on API 31 (Android 12) or higher. Instead, it seems to use FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED for everything. It also appears that the `setFilterTouchesWhenObscured` and `onFilterTouchEventForSecurity` methods seem to be affected by this as well.

Looking up [FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) gave no info about this behavior. So I tested this on an emulator using API 29, 30, 31, and 33, and I can indeed confirm the flag is no longer 'working' starting at API 31.

Fortunately, API 31+ introduces a new method named [setHideOverlayWindows](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setHideOverlayWindows(boolean)) that can be used to hide any non-system overlay on the selected view. You will also need to use the [HIDE_OVERLAY_WINDOWS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#HIDE_OVERLAY_WINDOWS) permission.

Answer (score 2):

From Android 10 & onwards, we have to use **FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED**.